# SFSafariViewController no dark mode with custom bar tint color

Tags: ios, swift, sfsafariviewcontroller, ios-darkmode

I call `SFSafariViewController` from my app to open `myurl`. I changed the bar tint color of `SFSafariViewController`. This works fine using:

```
vc.preferredBarTintColor = UIColor.teal025
```

However when device changes appearance style mode from light to dark, the bar tint color remains **teal025** and doesn't adjust to a darker color, as default bar tint color does (e.g. light gray to dark gray) if not set using `preferredBarTintColor`.

Major parts of the app also use **teal025** as navigation bar tint color. These object adjust color automatically as desired, when entering dark mode.

How can I have the same behavior for SFSafariViewController bar tint color?

Here the entire code:

```
let urlString = "https://myurl"
if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
    let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
    vc.preferredBarTintColor = UIColor.teal025 // this prevents dark mode change
    vc.preferredControlTintColor = UIColor.teal100
    present(vc, animated: true)
}
```

NB1: I don't want to use `UIWebView` since myurl uses Google fonts, which don't show properly on iOS using `UIWebView`.

NB2: **teal025** and **teal100** are custom colors.

**--- UPDATE --- (10.01.2021)**

As requested, here how I define(d) my colors.

```
extension UIColor {
    static var teal025: UIColor { return UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 127.0/255.0, blue: 127.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0) } // 0x008080
}
```

**--- UPDATE --- (12.01.2021)**

My aim is to have a SFSafariViewController bar tint which has exactly the same color tints, gradient and translucency than the app's navigation bar. My navigation is type `Prefer Large Titles` style along with `scrollEdgeAppearance`. These two properties handle automatic light/dark preference changes as well as translucency and vertical color gradients. I believe SFSafariViewController doesn't have provisions for all that. So the closest would be the dynamicProvider initializer of UIColor, as suggested by CSmith. This would "only" address the light/dark preference change.

```
let urlString = "https://myurl"
if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
    let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
    vc.preferredBarTintColor = UIColor.safariBarTint
    vc.preferredControlTintColor = UIColor.safariControlTint
    present(vc, animated: true)
}

extension UIColor {
    struct Material {
        static var orangeA100: UIColor { return UIColor(red: 0xff / 0xff,
                                                        green: 0xd1 / 0xff,
                                                        blue:  0x80 / 0xff,
                                                        alpha: 1.0) } // #FFD180
        ...
        static var orangeA700: UIColor { return UIColor(red: 0xff / 0xff,
                                                        green: 0x6d / 0xff,
                                                        blue:  0x00 / 0xff,
                                                        alpha: 1.0) } // #FF6D00
    }
}

static var safariBarTint: UIColor {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        return UIColor { (traits: UITraitCollection) -> UIColor in
            return traits.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ?
                UIColor.Material.orangeA700 :
                UIColor.Material.orangeA100
        }
    } else { // for iOS 12 and earlier
        return UIColor.Material.orangeA100
    }
}
static var safariControlTint: UIColor {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        return UIColor { (traits: UITraitCollection) -> UIColor in
            return traits.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ?
                UIColor.Material.orangeA100 :
                UIColor.Material.orangeA700
        }
    } else { // for iOS 12 and earlier
        return UIColor.Material.orangeA700
    }
}
```

I believe a 1:1 color adaptation between app's navigation bar and SFSafariViewController must be done manually, hence remains a shot in the dark?!

I believe above code is the closest I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I observe `SFSafariViewController` properly respecting the light and dark variants of the `UIColor` set as `preferredBarTintColor`.  Your definition of **teal025** in the UIColor extension defines a single color variant (0x008080) and does not have a separate dark mode color.

To resolve define your **teal025** in a Color asset catalog and load the value using:

`preferredBarTintColor = UIColor.init(named:"teal025")`

Make sure to define both dark and light variants in the color asset by selecting "*Any,Dark*" for the setting `Appearance`, then set appropriate colors for each.

Or, use the dynamicProvider initializer of UIColor to return dark and light mode variants at run time, something like this:

```
extension UIColor 
{
    static var teal025: UIColor 
    {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) 
        {
            return UIColor { (traits: UITraitCollection) -> UIColor in
                
                // Return one of two colors depending on light or dark mode
                return traits.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ?
                    UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1) :
                    UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.4, blue: 0.4, alpha: 1)
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            // for iOS 12 and earlier
            return UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, and after better understanding your question, you're possibly perceiving that `SFSafariViewController` bar tint color looks different from your app because of bar translucency.  At present there is no means of accessing the `UINavigationBar` of `SFSafariViewController` to disable translucency.

Comment: Your code works. However I was (by mistake probably) under the "impression" that even custom UIColors would change **automatrically** when changing from light to dark mode, as the tint colors defined in storyboard do. Isn't it possible to define a UIColor in code which does exactly that automatically (your code does that, but manually)? If not, how can I determine the (system generated) RGB values of the dark mode color, given a specific light mode color?

Comment: I edited my answer to show color asset catalog as the preferred approach, this will handle automatic updating when user changes device dark/light mode setting

Comment: Please also note there is no such concept as "system generated RGB values of the dark mode color given a specific light mode color".  You could decide that teal025 is always 0x008080 in both dark and light modes, or tweak the RGB values slightly for best appearance.

Comment: You say that the asset catalog approach is preferred as it will automatically handle changes when the user changes light/dark preference. I used your suggested extension UIColor code now, and this one also makes the desired UI changes as soon as light/dark preference is changed. In other words ... I don't see a difference between asset catalog and extension UIColor code approach in this respect.

Comment: I accepted your answer even if it wasn't exactly answering my question. But my question doesn't seem to have a definite answer as I phrased it, since I was assuming that for a given light color, the system would generate **automatically** dark color upon preference change, which was incorrect.

Comment: sadly the **navigationController** property of SFSafariViewController seems to be nil, so you can't access the navigationBar to do things like disable translucency, at least not that I'm aware of as of iOS 14